# Finding maximum alternating sum of digits (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm asked to write a function which finds the maximum alternating sum of digits in a given number and a given number of digits. For example, the number 81010 has 3 alternating sum with length 3 - (8-1+0),(1-0+1),(0-1+0) and we are supposed to return the answer 7.

It is easy to sum every sub sequence of digits, but it can take a while and the algorithm should be fast enough to deal with very big numbers. I don't know how to write such function with runs faster than the trivial one...

Iv'e a clue which says to think how by given the sum of first n digits we can effectively find the sum of the digits starting with the second digit in the sequence.

Please help, thanks.

PS
I did saw some question about finding the biggest sum, but couldn't manage to implement the answers for finding the biggest alternating sum.

That's the code for finding the biggest sum of consecutive digits:

```
def max_sum(n,d):
    number = list(map(int,str(n)))
    maximum = current = sum(number[:d])
    for i in range(0, len(number)-d):
        current = current - number[i] + number[i+d]
        if current > maximum: 
           maximum = current
    return maximum
```

Comment: Post your code so we can see if you are doing something inefficiently. Don't say "here's my problem, write me fast code please"

Comment: In addition to what Cyber said, question around "optimization" should really be posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1. Negate every even number (81010 -> 8 -1 0 -1 0), find biggest_sum_1 starting at an odd position
2. Negate every odd number (81010 -> -8 1 0 1 0), find biggest_sum_2 starting at an even position
3. Return max(biggest_sum_1, biggest_sum_2)
```

You asked for the algorithm, so this should be migrated to the Theoretical Computer Science site.

EDIT: added python code

```
def max_alt_sum(n,d):
  number = list(map(int,str(n)))
  negatedEven = []
  negatedOdd = []
  for i,v in enumerate(number):
    if i%2==0:
      negatedOdd.append(v)
      negatedEven.append(-v)
    else:
      negatedOdd.append(-v)
      negatedEven.append(v)
  maximum = sum(negatedEven[:d])
  for i in range(0, len(str(n))-d+1):
    if i%2==0:
      current = sum(negatedOdd[i:i+d])
    else:
      current = sum(negatedEven[i:i+d])
    if current > maximum:
      maximum = current
  return maximum
```

Comment: I managed to do it, but know i face another problem. The first digit in the sequence has to be positive and I don't how to make it...

Comment: I still don't know how to it... can you post an answer with a code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I checked the code again and it's not working quite well. For example, for n=43805 and d=3 we are supposed to return 13, but it returns 9. How can it be fixed?

Comment: Oh, sorry, the `range` function is not inclusive, so `+1` is needed

Comment: mirelon, just an FYI, the code doesn't run, there's an error on `for i in range(0, len(n)-d+1):`, the error is `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`. @Galc127 be advised.

Comment: Thanks, I only tested it when n was string (n="81010"), so I edited the answer.

Comment: Great. Can you please explain what the second `for` does ?

Comment: Just finds a maximum sum of a substring in arrays `negatedOdd` and `negatedEven`, with the parity condition on i ( =substring start).

Comment: Okay, I don't understand why there's `-d+1` in: `for i in range(0, len(str(n))-d+1):`.

Comment: For iterating all substrings of length `d`, the start of the substring must be in that range.